# Tangent of an Ellipse

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

For the curve described by this expression answer the following questions:

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 = 7$$

Find the equation(s) of all lines tangent to the curve at $x = -1$.

Give line in slope-intercept form. If there is more than one line, please indicate to which point the line corresponds.

Comment: $xx_1+\frac12 (xy_1+x_1y)+yy_1=7$ (let $(x_1,y_1)\to(x,y)$ to get the equation back.) If $(x_1,y_1)=(-1,-2)$, the tangent there is $-x+\frac12 (-2x-y)-2y=7$ and if $(x_1,y_1)=(-1,3)$ the tangent there is $-x+\frac12 (3x-y)+3y=7.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

To begin with, start by determining the points of the ellipse which have $x = -1$ as its abscissa:
\begin{align*}
(-1)^{2} + (-1)y + y^{2} = 7 \Longrightarrow y^{2} - y - 6 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (y = -2)\vee(y = 3)
\end{align*}

Then you can make use of implicit differentiation to obtain the relation among $x,y$ and $y'$:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + xy + y^{2} = 7 \Longrightarrow 2x + y + xy' + 2yy' = 0
\end{align*}

Now plugin the pairs of values $(-1,-2)$ and $(-1,3)$ with the purpose of finding the corresponding slopes.

Can you take it from here?